# How to select multiple child elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, appendto

Total jQuery newbie here. Using this example HTML, I want to use jQuery to move every span.caption inside the preceding A tag.

Before:

```
 <ul class="gallery">
 <li><a href="http://mysite.com/mural.jpg"><img src="mural.jpg"/></a>     
 <span class="caption">Nice mural</span>
 </li>
 <li><a href="http://mysite.com/car.jpg"><img src="car.jpg"/></a>     
 <span class="caption">New car</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Desired result:

```
 <ul class="gallery">
 <li><a href="http://mysite.com/mural.jpg"><img src="mural.jpg"/>     
 <span class="caption">Nice mural</span></a>
 </li>
 <li><a href="http://mysite.com/car.jpg"><img src="car.jpg"/>     
 <span class="caption">New car</span></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I tried `$('ul.gallery li span.caption').appendTo($('ul.gallery li a img'));` but it selects every span.caption and positions them inside the first img tag.

I think I need to use a parent-child selector in some way, but confused about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flip your logic a bit and use `append()`.

```
$('.gallery a').append(function() {
    return $(this).nextAll('.caption');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnCes/).

I find this easier to read myself, but YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to iterate over the matched set of `.caption` elements, and [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to access the immediately preceding element (the `a` in your case):

```
$(".caption").each(function() {
    var caption = $(this);
    caption.appendTo(caption.prev()); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rTsxG/) (inspect the source with Firebug to see the result)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.caption').each(function(){$(this).prev().append($(this))});
```

Comment: To make it a little less noisy when doing it on one line, you can omit constructing the jQuery object when passing `this` to `append()`.